# html2pdf not respecting div width and height explicitly set

Tags: javascript, html-to-pdf

I am building my div element and putting it inside the html2pdf library ([link](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/blob/master/README.md)) when I generate the PDF. I am generating the size for the div element with such JS logic:

```
switch (sizeSelected) {
    case '3x5':
        canvasSizeObj.width = 288;
        canvasSizeObj.height = 480;
        break;
    case '4x6':
        canvasSizeObj.width = 384;
        canvasSizeObj.height = 576;
        break;
    case '5x7':
        canvasSizeObj.width = 480;
        canvasSizeObj.height = 672;
        break;
    case '8x8':
        canvasSizeObj.width = 768;
        canvasSizeObj.height = 768;
        break;
}

var divContent = document.createElement('div'),
    popupDOMContent = document.createElement('div');

    divContent.classList.add('popupDOMContent');
    divContent.setAttribute('style','height:'+canvasSizeObj.height+'px');
    divContent.setAttribute('style','width:'+canvasSizeObj.width+'px');
    document.body.appendChild(divContent);
    popupDOMContent.classList.add('popupDOMContent');

html2pdf()
    .set({filename:petName+'_Kennel_Card_'+sizeSelected+'.pdf',margin:1})
    .from(popupDOMContent)
    .save();

popupDOMContent.remove();
```

I can see the element on the body if I choose to not remove it, and I can see the size is set for the element in below screenshot:
[image]

But when I open up the PDF, it is not honoring that size and instead full width, as seen in below screenshot:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Don't set the size of the canvas, set the size of the PDF. Something like:

```
html2pdf()
    .set({
        filename:petName+'_Kennel_Card_'+sizeSelected+'.pdf',
        margin:1
        jsPDF: {format:[canvasSizeObj.width,canvasSizeObj.height]}
     })
    .from(popupDOMContent)
    .save();
```